# Some xAxis labels are not showing in Highchart : Area Chart

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to show 6 point's on the Chart in highchart. Now the points are get easily plot on the chart but some respective x-axis labels are missing.

I want to show all x-axis labels without increasing chart width.

[image: here you can see missing x-axis labels]

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        height: 200,
        width: 300
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        visible: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {

    },
    series: [{
        name: '',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }]
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yogfiddle/my2wt3ea/5/)

I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/my2wt3ea/6/ Used tickInterval

Comment: @RahulSharma Thank you Rahul very much... please add you answer below so that I can marked as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `tickInterval` property in xAxis. set `tickInterval` as below

```
xAxis: {
   tickInterval: 1
}
```

this answer is given by [@Rahul Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5929690/rahul-sharma) in above comment section